# SQL - Subselect / divide two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, subquery

I have this query for my magento shop:

```
SELECT date_format(sfo.shipping_arrival_date,"%d.%m.%Y") AS DeliveryDate,
       count(sfo.entity_id) AS NoOfOrders,
       sum(
             (SELECT if(count(s.customer_email)>1,0,1)
              FROM sales_flat_order AS s
              WHERE s.customer_email=sfo.customer_email
                AND (s.status = 'pending'
                     OR s.status = 'processing'))) AS NewCustomers,
       sum(
             (SELECT if(count(s.customer_email)>1,1,0)
              FROM sales_flat_order AS s
              WHERE s.customer_email=sfo.customer_email
                AND (s.status = 'pending'
                     OR s.status = 'processing'))) AS ExistingCustomers,

             (SELECT count(*)
              FROM sales_flat_order AS s
              WHERE s.shipping_method = "freeshipping_freeshipping"
                AND s.shipping_arrival_date = sfo.shipping_arrival_date
                AND (s.status = 'pending'
                     OR s.status = 'processing')) AS NoOfCustomersThatPickUp                
FROM sales_flat_order AS sfo
WHERE sfo.status <> 'canceled'
  AND sfo.shipping_arrival_date <> ''
GROUP BY DeliveryDate
ORDER BY sfo.shipping_arrival_date DESC
```

It lists the number of orders, new customers, existing customers and no of customers who pick up their order in one table.

I now want to divide the number of customers who pick up with the total number of orders, but when I add this line:

```
NoOfCustomersThatPickUp/NoOfOrders
```

I get this error:

```
Error running query: Unknown column 'NoOfCustomersThatPickUp' in 'field list'
```

Does somebody knows how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use a subquery if you want to refer to the column aliases.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff That works.